# How to set up automatic translation importing for a particular branch in Launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, translation

I've run into a problem setting up translations for a project in Launchpad. My project consists of a [code branch](https://code.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/stackapplet/stackapplet-qt) and a [translations branch](https://code.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/stackapplet/translations). I have a [daily build recipe](https://code.launchpad.net/~stackapplet-dev/+recipe/stackapplet-daily) that nests one branch in the other and builds the binary packages.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to set up automatic translations for a particular branch - only a particular series. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Launchpad can have automatic translations for series only - see [Importing templates](https://help.launchpad.net/Translations/YourProject/ImportingTemplates#Push_the_branch_to_Launchpad) page

Comment: It looks like you've already sorted it out. Looking at https://translations.launchpad.net/stackapplet/1.6/+translations-settings just a comment - you can use the same branch for both the import and export, so that all is completely automatic and you don't have to bother manually merging translations

Comment: So the next step should be to announce that the project is up for translation on the ubuntu-translators and launchpad-translators mailing lists.